# Error al crear un Projecto xamarin en VS2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

estuve instalando y actualizando xamarin en el Visual Studio 2015, cuando trato de crear una aplicacion, me manda este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas intentando utilizar versiones de los paquetes no compatible con tu **Target Framework**, para esto debes ir a la pestaña de *project > [project name] properties...* y en el apartado de *Application* seleccionar el *Target* requerido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso **se requiere una version de 7.0** o superior para que restaure e instale los paquetes sin problemas.

Antes de descargar algún paquete Nuget, revisa sus dependencias, así te aseguras que paquetes instalara y que *target* requiere para hacerlo.

Puedes buscar los paquetes Nuget en su portal oficial: [https://www.nuget.org/](https://www.nuget.org) y en la pestaña de *Dependencias* encontraras que paquetes necesitara instalar para funcionar y que version de mono android necesitaras especificar en tu *Target*.

**Nota:** si en algún momento no te sale un target en especifico, debes actualizar tu version de Visual Studio e instalar los SDKs correspondientes en la pestaña de visual studio, *Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager*.