# ¿Por qué no puedo instalar el Nuget?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, nuget

Estoy intentando instalar en mi app `Xamarin.Android` el siguiente Nuget:

**Firebase.Xamarin** *by Ricardo*.
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Firebase.Xamarin)

Pero me da el siguiente error y no se como resolverlo, y tampoco quisiera sustituir el nuget por otro porque es un tutorial muy específico el que estoy siguiendo y he probado un par de opciones y no me funcionan como deberían en el código.

Error:

```
Install-Package : NU1202: El paquete Firebase.Xamarin 0.3.6 no es compatible con monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). El paquete Firebase.Xamarin 0.3.6 admite: net 
(.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package Firebase.Xamarin -Version 0.3.6
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Error al restaurar el paquete. Revirtiendo los cambios del paquete para 'ChatAppUsingFirebase'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Install-Package Firebase.Xamarin -Version 0.3.6
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Tuto: (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-chat-application-u/)

[image: Error]

Comment: Agrega las versiones del SDK y versión que utilizas de Xamarin y Mono.

Comment: Tal y como dice @fredyfx lo mas probable es que sea una diferencia de versión entre el paquete Nuget y .NetFramework asegurate de tener ambas compatibles entre si

Comment: No entiendo como puedo hacer eso @fredyfx? Me puedes dar alguna directiva?

Comment: Lee [Esta respuesta completa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/227821/38154) y déjame saber si te funciona.